# Исключение "Could not bind socket..."

Tags: delphi

Что обозначает эта ошибка?

[image]

Comment: Только не "ошибка", а "исключение".

Comment: приводите лучше код, где произошла исключительная ситуация. Так проще понять ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это значит, что на порту, который вы пытались начать слушать, кто-то из локальных приложений уже висит. Можно узнать, кто именно, например, майкрософтовской утилитой TCPView.

Comment: еще ``netstat -a``